# RxJava in Android has no Observable.create?

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-java

I'm trying to run this example from [here](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%202%20-%20Sequence%20Basics/1.%20Creating%20a%20sequence.md)

```
Observable<String> values = Observable.create(o -> {
    o.onNext("Hello");
    o.onCompleted();
});
Subscription subscription = values.subscribe(
    v -> System.out.println("Received: " + v),
    e -> System.out.println("Error: " + e),
    () -> System.out.println("Completed")
);
```

Aside from the fact that I can't use Lambda in Android Studio, there is no Observable.create(). The only option I have is Observable.class?

I'm using version 1.1.6 and getting the library via Gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ has probably imported `java.util.*` which includes `java.util.Observable`

Add an import for `rx.Observable` and it should work again.

Comment: Ah that got me, what a sneaky thing.

Comment: @MagicMarbles I pretty much only know that because I've encountered it far too many times